# Tips for publishing a summary of an article to be published

Tags: publications, self-citation

I want to write a short article about a paper that has been accepted for publication in an upcoming conference. This short article summarizes the accepted one and will end up in my workplace's digital library. The reason mainly is to make the article to be more accessible and understandable to undergraduate students.

In this summary, I should cite the upcoming article to be published. However, I doubt where I can put that citation of the upcoming article to avoid putting it everywhere in my short article. For example, in the methodology, experimentation and results I will present a summary of the original article. However, I do not think it will look nice if I should put something like this in every paragraph: "According to Layla[2020]...", "the Experiments made by Layla[2020]," and so on. What can I do with this sort of "self-citation".

I have been trying to find examples on the web about this situation, but I could not find anything. Any help would be useful.

Comment: You don't cite it here and there. You make clear that any reader understand that s/he is reading the summary of an article. This can be done in the intro section, or by "TITLE*".... *this is a summary of xxxyyyzzz, Layla, 2020... Etc etc.

Comment: Alchimista's comment is good. Moreover, you should look at the many summaries of articles that exist -- Science and Nature have short articles that comment and summarize research articles in each week's issue, and they don't require convoluted or repeated references since it's clear from the start what paper is being referred to. There are lots of informal summaries as well, e.g. mine: https://eighteenthelephant.com/2020/04/10/putting-the-brakes-on-gut-bacteria/